# More than 200 stores with multi store and same products?

Tags: performance, magento

we have 250k products and we want to create more than 200 different site(multi site) all stores will have same products but different domain and different design. Magento multi site function is good for us but you need to match every product and every site so that means 50m(min) record for tables like "catalog_product_website"(and some other tables) and also flat catalog and indexing will be a real problem.

if we use store and store view than userbase will be same and also flat catalog will be problem.

So my question, is there any way to make all these stores work like single store? Or is there any way to make it work with nice performance?

Comment: I think it's works with Store Manager for Magento (http://www.mag-manager.com/)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.

While Magento is built for multi-site applications, I don't think it's suited to running 200+ stores with 250,000 products.

At that size, I'd say contact Magento regarding Magento Enterprise to see what they have to say. Oh, and be prepared to pay the $15,000/Server/Year price.

Comment: I can second this. For every storeview (every store has a at least one storeview), Magento will create a copy of its flat tables, containing all product information. Rebuilding the indexes will get horribly slow, which will also slow down loading and saving products.